# How Approval Processes Actions will be done after the freezing of workflows?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, approval-process, workflow-field-update

Salesforce has announced that they will be [retiring](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/go-with-the-flow-whats-happening-with-workflow-rules-and-process-builder) their Workflow Rules and Process Builder functionality.

As a result, users will no longer be able to create new workflows or make changes to existing ones.

This change raises concerns about how the Approval Process will be handled, specifically regarding the actions of Approval, Rejection, Final Approval, and Final Rejection, which are based on workflow field updates.

Given that, are there options to overcome this loss in functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this article which says the [below](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389396&type=1)

> What about Approval Processes, Email Alerts, and other functionality operating on the workflow engine?

> There are no plans to retire any of these auxiliary features; however, each of them can be leveraged through flow (or Flow Orchestrator, in the case of approval processes), without the need to use processes or workflow rules at all.

Comment: Thank you for your input, @saipraveen-kakkirala. It appears that only "workflow rules" have been frozen in the Winter 23 release. As a result, the use of "workflow actions" by Approval Processes remains a viable option. However, Salesforce does recommend utilizing Flow Orchestration as an alternative to Workflow Rules and Actions.

Comment: @LeandroFerreiraFernandes, Yes the article says the same.